# How to suppress warnings for a specific third-party header file's include in STM32CubeIDE (based on Eclipse)?

Tags: eclipse, warnings, gcc-warning, pragma, stm32cubeide

I was wondering if I can disable warnings for a particular header file's include in a STM32CubeIDE project? The compiler is gcc. I followed this [recommendation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) and "guarded" a header with pragmas, but it did not work for me.

Comment: Suspending warnings is never the solution. Write the header properly and you will not have any problems

Comment: It is a third-party header. I need to disable warnings temporarily.

Comment: How exactly did the pragma not work?

Comment: @TomV I did:
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wunused-variable"
#include "<third-party-header>.h"
#pragma GCC diagnostic pop

However, after I cleaned and rebuilt my project, warnings were still displayed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no control over the third party code, you can use
-isystem instead of -I
GCC have a special treatment of system includes, one of them is to not raise warnings on things you don't control.